# MySQL trigger with if statement trying to query a different table for value to be inserted

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, declare

I am setting up some triggers so that if there is an update on a table for a value it will trigger to insert some fields into a changelog table. On the original update I have foreign keys setup so that the keys are changed so the value is not used at all.

The following is my SQL and I keep getting a syntax error:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `history_hosts_modify`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `history_hosts_modify` BEFORE UPDATE ON `hosts`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.hostname != NEW.hostname THEN
      INSERT INTO changelogs (cid, remoteid, cat, action, oldval, newval, modified) VALUES(NULL, OLD.id, 'HOST', 'MOD', OLD.hostname, NEW.hostname, NOW());
    END IF;
    IF OLD.clients_id != NEW.clients_id THEN
      DECLARE TEMP1, TEMP2 INT;
      SELECT client FROM clients WHERE id=OLD.clients_id INTO TEMP1;
      SELECT client FROM clients WHERE id=NEW.clients_id INTO TEMP2;
      INSERT INTO changelogs (cid, remoteid, cat, action, oldval, newval, modified) VALUES(NULL, OLD.id, 'HOST', 'MOD', TEMP1, TEMP2, NOW());
    END IF;
  END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: **`I keep getting a syntax error`** → please post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> [13.6.3 DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html)
>
> ...
>
> [DECLARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html) is permitted only inside a [BEGIN ... END](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/begin-end.html) compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `history_hosts_modify`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `history_hosts_modify` BEFORE UPDATE ON `hosts`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE TEMP1, TEMP2 INT;
    IF OLD.hostname != NEW.hostname THEN
        INSERT INTO changelogs (cid, remoteid, cat, action, oldval, newval, modified)
        VALUES
        (NULL, OLD.id, 'HOST', 'MOD', OLD.hostname, NEW.hostname, NOW());
    END IF;
    IF OLD.clients_id != NEW.clients_id THEN
        -- DECLARE TEMP1, TEMP2 INT;
        SELECT client FROM clients WHERE id=OLD.clients_id INTO TEMP1;
        SELECT client FROM clients WHERE id=NEW.clients_id INTO TEMP2;
        INSERT INTO changelogs (cid, remoteid, cat, action, oldval, newval, modified)
        VALUES
        (NULL, OLD.id, 'HOST', 'MOD', TEMP1, TEMP2, NOW());
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I was able to solve it..

```
IF OLD.clients_id != NEW.clients_id THEN
    SELECT hostname FROM hosts WHERE id=OLD.id INTO @TEMP;
    SELECT client FROM clients WHERE id=OLD.clients_id INTO @TEMP1;
    SELECT client FROM clients WHERE id=NEW.clients_id INTO @TEMP2;
        INSERT INTO changelogs (cid, itemname, cat, action, oldval, newval, modified) VALUES(NULL, @TEMP, 'HOST', 'MOD', @TEMP1, @TEMP2, NOW());
END IF;
```

thank you!!